# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher Version inconsistency 4.9.0 and 4.11.0 How to resolve?

Tags: android, logging, retrofit2, okhttp, android-glide

Here is my okhttp gradle version:

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'`

And my okHttp logger library.

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'`

I found out the issue on github with a response at here saying this is due to version inconsistency. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2839#issuecomment-244923226

But Okhttp logger hasn't updated their library OkHttp version which is `4.9.0` but okHttp is `4.11.0` . I can lower the version to `4.9.0` but I didn't want to. just like Jake Wharton's recommendation here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2839#issuecomment-245269471

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: tech.guzo.awtar, PID: 7624
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method log(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/platform/Platform; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform' appears in /data/app/tech.guzo.awtar-XZo1TJ-jaQnVlyXeTlwUdQ==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:111)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:159)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at com.yenepay.yegid.net.ServerAPI$1.intercept(ServerAPI.java:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Can someone give me direction on how you have overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on transient dependencies, you should just list all versions you rely on at runtime as your direct dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
```

Comment: so down grading my version is the only means? keeping all versions the same right? I have checked and this works well.. so I think I should keep it this way .. Thank @yuri-schimke

Comment: This should be upgrading everything to 4.9.0 now. 4.11.0 is glide which is another project.